# Unable to import sox package in python after successful installation

Tags: python, conda, sox

I installed sox using the command '**conda install -c conda-forge sox**' and pysox using '**conda install -c davidbgonzalez pysox**'. But when I try to import sox it says 'No module named sox'. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the examples at https://pythonhosted.org/pysox/intro.html#simple-examples, you need to import `pysox`, not `sox`:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 23 2018, 18:31:10) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pysox # or the one below
>>> from pysox import sox
```

Also, the first time you try this, you may see the error:

```
>>> import pysox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/p/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysox/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from pysox.sox import CSoxStream, CEffect, CEffectsChain, CPysoxPipeStream
ImportError: libsox.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That's because conda-forge has provided sox v14.4.2 (it provides libsox.so.3) and pysox provided by davidbgonzalez was built against an older version.

Looking at https://abi-laboratory.pro/index.php?view=timeline&l=sox and hoping that this build of pysox doesn't use any of the removed symbols, you can then fix this problem by creating a symlink and crossing your fingers:

```
$ ln -s $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/libsox.so.{3,2}

$ ls -l $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/libsox.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 nwani nwani 22 Nov 10 23:54 /tmp/p/lib/libsox.so.2 -> /tmp/p/lib/libsox.so.3
```